# FireStoreのユーザー情報の持たせ方について

Tags: vue.js, firebase

FireStoreにAuthとは別にユーザーの情報を持たせようと考えています。
(ユーザー固有の文字列ID、 プロフィール文等)

そこでusersコレクションを作成し、
そこにユーザーの情報を入れようにしようと考えているのですが、
主キーにAuthのuidを入れるべきか、
それ以外の値を入れるべきかわかりません。

実際に実装されている方は、
どのような形でusersコレクションを作成されているか教えていただきたいです。